# Every time a new record is added to the table, calculate the sum of the values by the column javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a little problem and I need help. I have a program in which, with each new addition or deletion of an entry to the table, the sum of the values in the "weight" column was calculated, looking at the "name" column.  If, for example, I have several entries with the name "chocolate", then I need to calculate the "weight" column, and if there are several rows with the name "chocolate", and then "coffee", then the weight column should be calculated only by the name "chocolate". Also, my data from the table is added to the postgresql database.

[image: screenshot]

This is my code to add to the database

```
    public ObservableList<BiscuitRecipe> getBiscuitMineIngredients(String name, Integer id_ing, Float weight, String photo) {

        try {
            String query = String.format("insert into biscuit(name, ingredientid, weight, photo) " +
                            "values('%s',' %s', '%s', '%s');",
                    name, id_ing, weight, photo);
            Statement statement = connect_to_db().createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

public class BiscuitRecipe {
    String name;
    int ing;
    float weight;

   String photo;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getIng() {
        return ing;
    }

    public void setIng(int ing) {
        this.ing = ing;
    }

    public float getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public BiscuitRecipe(String name, int ing, float weight, String photo) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ing = ing;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}


 public void addMineRecipeBiscuit() {
        
        String name = filedNameBiscuit.getText();
        int ingredientID = comboIngredients.getValue().getId(); 
        float weight = Float.parseFloat(filedWeightBiscuit.getText());
        String photo = image;
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty!");
        } else {
            dbFunctions.getBiscuitMineIngredients(name, ingredientID, weight, photo);
            tableBiscuit.setItems(dbFunctions.getBiscuitIngredients());
        }

    }
```

I need the amount to be displayed in the inscription "Sum" from the first picture. Please help me, how can I do this?

Comment: Not clear (to me) what you want. Let's say that your table contains 4 rows where 2 rows have the name "chocolate" and the other 2 rows have the name "coffee". Then  if the user selects one of the "coffee" rows, then, instead of _Sum_, you want to display the total weight of all the "coffee" rows. Is that correct?

Comment: Although this was closed due to a lack of debugging details, the real issue, (as noted by Abra), is that it is unclear what the question is actually asking.  The question is unfocused, the database portions aren't core to the issue being asked and so aren't needed in the question.  The code provided is confusing, e.g. a get method with a return value performing a database insert and always returning null.  It seems there should be three classes modeled (Recipe, Ingredient and RecipeIngredient), but there is only one (BiscuitRecipe).

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like you are creating new accounts to ask different questions. There is no advantage in that. We will notice. Use one account to ask questions. Doing this will help you build your reputation. Having a reputation will allow your account to be able to do more stuff.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77521954/how-to-transfer-data-from-a-table-to-another-table-in-another-window

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add a listener to you observableList

```
ObservableList<Integer> ob = FXCollections.observableArrayList(intList);
ob.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> c) {
        System.out.println("list changed. Put your action here");  
    }
});
```

Step 2: Calculate the sum

Get all rows, filter them by their names, get all their weights, and sum them together.

You can use the stream API for grouping them, e.g.:

```
var map = observableList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(BiscuitRecipe::getName)
```

Then get the values of the entries (this are lists) and sum their weights.