# How to transfer data from a table to another table in another window

Tags: java, postgresql, javafx

I'm just starting to learn java and I need help. I have a table with two parameters, the table (first photo) is filled with data from a postgresql database view (second photo).

[image]

[image]

```
public ObservableList<ViewBiscuit> getViewBiscuit() {
    ObservableList<ViewBiscuit> viewBiscuits = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        ResultSet resultSet = connect_to_db().createStatement().executeQuery(String.format("select * from sum_biscuit"));
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            viewBiscuits.add(new ViewBiscuit(
                    resultSet.getString("название"),
                    resultSet.getFloat("sum")
            ));
        }
        return viewBiscuits;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return viewBiscuits;
    }
}
```

This is the code for filling the table with data from the view

```
viewBiscuit.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
        ViewBiscuit viewBiscuit1 = viewBiscuit.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader2 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/example/demo/screens/update-biscuit.fxml"));
            Parent parent2 = loader2.load();
            UpdateBiscuitController updateBiscuitController = loader2.getController();
            updateBiscuitController.setData(viewBiscuit1.getName(), viewBiscuit1.getAmount());
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(parent2));
            stage.showAndWait();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code for transferring data from one window to another. But here this method outputs data from the table to text fields

This representation is made by a table, it outputs one parameter depending on another parameter.

This is the table on which the view is made

[image: some table]

When you click on a certain row in the table, another window should open, where the table should be filled with full parameters from the database (3 photo).

[image: some ui]

How can I do this? I don't quite understand.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You have one `TableView`, populated by data from a database table with two columns. You say that when the user clicks on a row in that table (i.e. selects an item in one of the rows), you want to display another `TableView` with data from another database table. What is the relationship between the two database tables? You haven't specified how you want to choose the data in the second table that should be displayed, given the selected item in the first table. It's also not clear exactly which part you're stuck on.

Comment: Why create a new account?

Comment: We need to see your database schema.

Comment: I would have things set up in a way that when I click a table row, the ID for that item is used to query the database for the additional information that will need to be displayed.

Comment: when you click on a row in the first TableView, all record data from the database with the same id is called as used to upload data to the first TableView. The record data from the database is uploaded to the second TableView in a new window. The problem is finding the id by the clicked line.

Comment: In my database I currently have one table - a table with four parameters.

Comment: I have already solved this problem, thanks for the help!